# Text-Shadow with transparent text color

Tags: css

I'm trying to achieve the design below using the `text-shadow` property in CSS but continue to get a solid color result. I've tried including a rgba value of `255,0,0,0.0` for the font-color and text-shadow as such:

```
  text-shadow:
   -1px -1px 0 #000,  
    1px -1px 0 #000,
    -1px 1px 0 #000,
     1px 1px 0 #000;
}
```

The results have been:
[image: bad result]

I'm looking to achieve:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest instead trying out the [text-stroke](https://caniuse.com/?search=text-stroke) property for the same effect and less trouble. Example below, cheers.

```css
body {
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/800/800) no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 7rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI';
  margin: 0;
  color: transparent;
  text-stroke: 2px #000;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 2px #000;
}
```

```html
<h1>NIFTY TEXT</h1>
```

Comment: I saw this before and would love to use it, but IE support is missing. What would you suggest as a fallback?

Comment: How long do you need to support IE? It reaches [end of life](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-it-pro-blog/internet-explorer-11-desktop-app-retirement-faq/ba-p/2366549) June next year but let me tinker, that's just the way I've done it other than using SVG instead of text.

Answer (score 0):

If you can’t use text-stroke you can fake it with a pseudo element and text-shadow.

```
h1 {
  font-size: 50pt;
  background: rgb(89,89,255);
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(89,89,255,1) 35%, rgba(0,212,255,1) 100%);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  color: transparent;
  z-index:1;
}
h1::before {
  content:"Hello World";
  position: absolute;
  top:45px;
  left:7.5px;
  font-size: 50pt;
  background:none;
  text-shadow: 1px 0 0 black, 0 1px 0 black, 0 -1px 0 black, -1px 0 0 black;
  -webkit-background-clip: none;
  -webkit-text-fill-color:  transparent;
  z-index:-1;
}
body {
background: rgb(89,89,255);
background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(89,89,255,1) 35%, rgba(0,212,255,1) 100%);
}
```

```
<h1>Hello World</h1>
```